# AngularJS - Scrollbar not loaded on state change, but loads on page refresh

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Currently when I tried load a page with an Id, using either `ui-sref="route({id: id})"` or `$state.go('route', {'id': id)`, it will load all the data into the page, but the default scrollbar will not load.

If I refresh the page, the default browser scroll bar will load, if I copy the URL to another browser window, the scrollbar will load.

Comment: Which scrollbar ? default browser or custom? Add sample code of table structure where you are populating the data.

Comment: The default scrollbar. There is no CSS preventing the scrollbar from appearing, ie `style="overflow: hidden"`